# what is meaning of spot labels and how to edit node pool on GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

why there is 2 labels related spot or not:

- cloud.google.com/gke-provisioning: spot
- cloud.google.com/gke-spot: "true"

what is the allowed values for this cloud.google.com/gke-provisioning label?
when I create a standard node (not spot) I found there is only:
cloud.google.com/gke-provisioning: standard but no cloud.google.com/gke-spot: false
this label: cloud.google.com/gke-provisioning is always exist?

when I edit manually from GKE UI the YAML file and change the values. this is update spot or not?

Answer (score 2):

This is well explained in [1] and [2] public documentation.

Creating node pools based on Spot VMs is only considered if unschedulable pods with a toleration for the `cloud.google.com/gke-spot="true":NoSchedule` taint exist. The taint is automatically applied to nodes in auto-provisioned node pools that are based on Spot VMs.

You can combine using the toleration with a `nodeSelector` or node affinity rule for the `cloud.google.com/gke-spot="true"` or `cloud.google.com/gke-provisioning=spot` (for nodes running GKE version 1.25.5-gke.2500 or later) node labels to ensure that your workloads only run on node pools based on Spot VMs.

GKE automatically adds both the `cloud.google.com/gke-spot=true` and `cloud.google.com/gke-provisioning=spot` (for nodes running GKE version 1.25.5-gke.2500 or later) labels to nodes that use Spot VMs. You can schedule specific Pods on nodes that use Spot VMs using the nodeSelector field in your Pod spec.

These are the allowed values:

```
    cloud.google.com/gke-provisioning=spot
    cloud.google.com/gke-provisioning=preemptible
    cloud.google.com/gke-provisioning=standard
```

[1] https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/spot-vms#scheduling-workloads

[2] https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/node-auto-provisioning#support_for_spot_vms